# Animating listview header out

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I need to implement a list view so that above it I have a header image and a title.

I want it so that when you scroll down the list, the header will fade out and the list will scroll over it.

I can't figure out how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few libraries that can help you with this.

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/QuickReturnHeader

https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

Hope this helps.